# How can I avoid the "save changes" window when running an action on several documents in Adobe Acrobat Pro?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

How can I avoid the "save changes" window when running an action on several documents in Adobe Acrobat Pro?

For example, if I use this action to convert documents into PDF:

[image]

Save Settings:

[image]

Then apply the action on a folder containing one .doc document and one .docx documents:

[image]

I get:

[image]

which I don't want, since I need to batch process many documents without having to supervise it.

Comment: This seems really odd and doesn't make a lot of sense for Adobe to build the process like that.  Just to confirm, a,pdf doesn't exist prior to this?  Do you get a similar confirmation on each file if you manually continue the process?  Does the process actually halt until you confirm the first file (as opposed to presenting the confirmation dialog but continuing in the background, building a collection of confirmations to handle before you close)?  Have you done anything to confirm that Acrobat isn't corrupted?

Comment: @fixer1234 "This seems really odd and doesn't make a lot of sense for Adobe to build the process like that." -> yes I must have missed something.

Comment: @fixer1234  "Just to confirm, a,pdf doesn't exist prior to this?" yes, no PDF exists before I execute the action.

Comment: @fixer1234  "Do you get a similar confirmation on each file if you manually continue the process?" -> yes

Comment: @fixer1234 " Does the process actually halt until you confirm the first file (as opposed to presenting the confirmation dialog but continuing in the background, building a collection of confirmations to handle before you close)?" -> yes

Comment: @fixer1234 " Have you done anything to confirm that Acrobat isn't corrupted?" -> how can I confirm that?

Comment: re: confirming corruption -- reinstall the latest version or rollback to a previous version, or try to replicate it on another machine.  Your question is like dandruff (a head scratcher).  :-)  There are endless utilities to convert Word files to PDF (many free).  If you don't quickly discover the problem, it might be faster to just try other programs.  BTW, IIRC, you can do a lot of PDF-related stuff natively from the command line in Linux.  You might be able to batch the conversion without needing an application.  I've never done it, but it's another avenue to check.

Comment: @fixer1234 I see, I have recently updated Adobe Acrobat so I'm pretty sure it's ok. If anyone knows any good tool, you're most welcome to add an answer  on [Batch convert Microsoft Word documents to PDF](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50002/903)

Comment: I ran into the same problem when trying a hack to print hundreds of first-pages-only. I batch-delete all pages after respective page one and print. And then I want to just close the batch-action without saving anything and without clicking hundreds of confirmations. So this is my "me too please". Seems basically we are looking for a "silent" option with "confirm everything" or "refuse everything". Links to more documentation are welcome.